# Человек зачитывает устно предложение/слово и инструмент оценивает произношение (условно как в караоке)

Tags: распознавание-речи

Мне бы хотелось понять существует ли готовое решение или можно ли разработать что-то, что когда человек произносит слово на русском и инструмент проверяет насколько идеально человек произнес то или иное слово. Как я понимаю, это про распознавание речи, про оценку схожести звукового паттерна. Такое решение, например, есть у Rosetta Stone.
Как дорого это стоит и как долго займет?

Спасибо.

Comment: На каком языке?